# How do I parse temporal strings to temporal types in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a standard datetime string from an external service:

```
"2021-12-14T14:29:59.909124272Z"
```

How can I parse this into a native KDB type? I've tried casting it to the various types, but it never seems to parse right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q)"P"$"2021-12-14T14:29:59.909124272Z"
2021.12.14D14:29:59.909124272
```